# Generating a URL independant of controllers in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, urlhelper

I have an mvc 3 application with a background thread checking on the state of some database items.  When it finds an expired item, it sends out an email.  In the email, I would like to include the url for the action to call to see the status.  If this was done from a controller I would use the UrlHelper, eg:

```
string body_url = "For more details see: " + Url.Action("Details", "MyOrder", new { OrderId = order.OrderId }, Constants.HttpProtocol);
```

However, I'm not in a controller, nor is my method called from a controller, it is started on application start.  Is there a way to generate a valid UrlHelper, or, if not, to generate a valid URL without resorting to hard-coding paths, when independent of the controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is theoretical... ref [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031995/call-urlhelper-in-models-in-asp-net-mvc) ... being on a background thread makes things interesting :)

```
var request = new HttpRequest("/", "http://example.com", ""); //hopefully you can hardcode this or pull from config?
var response = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
var httpContext = new HttpContext(request, response);

var httpContextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext);
var routeData = new RouteData();
var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContextBase, routeData);

var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
var url = urlHelper.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

Comment: It seems a shame to have to hard-code the base URL, especially given it can change depending on whether I am running test or production.  I  would have hoped there was some way of grabbing the base URL from the app.

Comment: You can pass the HttpContext.Current information into your background thread when you spin it up.. be sure to only use the base url portion of it though! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398717/asp-net-get-websites-url-without-httpcontext-current-running-in-background-t

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` isn't available at application start, which is when @SimonParker wants to be able to generate a route URL.

Comment: @SimonParker You can do some tricky stuff with `Microsoft.Web.Administration.WebConfigurationManager` to get a list of current site bindings at runtime. Then you can just grab the first binding. It's ugly, but it works!